# Push GCLID to ZOHO crm

Tags: integration, google-ads-api, zoho

I have done with integration between ZOHO CRM & Google Ads but want to know what would be the placeholder for these text:
`"CMPjuu-Xx78CFRSTjgodPHsA3Q</FL>"`
shown below in my third party web form.

`val="GCLID">CMPjuu-Xx78CFRSTjgodPHsA3Q</FL> </row>`

For reference:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/google-adwords/configure.html

Note: *GCLID* needs to push in ZOHO, we have done all script part etc. But confused to what value must put on those specified placeholder in my script mentioned in link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the value, manually, via API (get the value from the URL).
The variable name is `$gclid`